# Add a external link to system configuration tab

Tags: magento-1.9, system-config

Is it possiible to add an external link to system config tab? Usually, when you create new section, you can add link to system config only, but in my case, I want to add a link to custom module grid.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the `Block` class of your custom template you can use method `getUrl()` to generate the link:

```
return $this->getUrl('adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/[name_of_the_extension]');
```